# How to output letter array from number array

Tags: javascript, rsa

I am trying to encrypt some text data with a public key + private key, but all I am seeing is NaN on the HTML side of things.

I've tried changing the nature of some of the variables, but that didn't work. Thank you

```
function letterValue(str){
    var anum={
        a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11,
        l: 12, m: 13, n: 14,o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20,
        u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26
    }
    if(str.length== 1) return anum[str] || ' ';
    return str.split('').map(letterValue);
}

function encryptText() {
  var p = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var q = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var n = p*q;
  const e = Math.pow(2, 16) + 1;
  var plaintext = document.getElementById('plaintext');
  var c = letterValue(String(plaintext));
  var ciphertext = c.map((el) => Math.pow(el, e) % n);
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = "Encrypted text = " + ciphertext;
}
```

I expected to get letter array, but that is not what I am receiving.

Comment: `document.getElementById('plaintext')` returns the HTMLElement, you'll want to put `.value` behind that. (when it comes to debugging, make sure you test the individual parts of your program. something like `console.log(letterValue("test"))` would've immediately shown to you that the problem has nothing to do with your encryption logic)

Comment: if, of course, the element with the ID plaintext is an input field

Comment: Corrected that just now, but I am getting the same result. Should I be using .value even for non-numerical values, such as text? Thanks

Comment: `.value` returns what the user put in the field, regardless of the type of field. `.value` isn't used to turn the text into a number.

Comment: You should provide the html.

Comment: You're using really big numbers, and logging them gives `Infinity`. Casting that to text gives `NaN`. You need to use a library that supports huge numbers.

Comment: @ChrisG `Infinity.toString()` is `"Infinity"`. But `Infinity % anyNumber` is `NaN`

Comment: @Turtlefight Right, I didn't test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript numbers only have finite precision.
`Math.pow(x, Math.pow(2, 16) + 1)` will exceed the maximal representable value (`1.7976931348623157e+308`, `Number.MAX_VALUE`) quite quickly.
e.g. `x >= 2` will always result in `Infinity`.

And `Infinity % anyNumber` is `NaN`, that is why you're getting lots of `NaN`s.

To fix this, you need to use an arbitrary-precision number library,
e.g.:

- [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/)
- [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)
- [crunch.js](http://crunch.js.org/)
- etc...

If you're using a transpiler like babel, or don't mind if your code doesn't work on some browsers, you could try the new [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type.
Example with `BigInt`s:

```js
function letterValue(str){
    if(str.length== 1) {
      if(str >= "a" && str <= "z")
        return str.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
      else
        return 0;
    }
    return str.split('').map(letterValue);
}


function encryptText(text) {
  // TODO: choose better values for p and q
  var p = 173n;
  var q = 149n;
  var n = p*q;
  // beware: you should avoid Math functions with BigInts, because
  // those operate on numbers, so you will loose precision with them.
  // you can use ** instead of Math.pow though to work around that.
  const e = 2n ** 16n + 1n;
  var c = letterValue(String(text));
  var ciphertext = c.map(el => (BigInt(el) ** e) % n);
  return ciphertext;
}

// the .map(e => e.toString()) is only for stackoverflow to correctly display the result.
console.log(encryptText("abc").map(e => e.toString()));
```

Edit: A full working RSA example:

```js
// choose two distinct primes: p, q
const p = 173n;
const q = 149n;
const n = p * q;
const phi = (p - 1n) * (q - 1n);

// choose two integer numbers e,d so that
// gcd(e, phi) == 1
// e != d
// (e*d) % phi == 1

// In a normal RSA implementation e would be picked randomly from this set of values: 3,5,17,257,65537
// and then calculate d = modinv(e, phi)
const e = 3n; 
const d = 16971n;

// then this will be your private / public keys:
const privateKey = {d, n};
const publicKey = {e, n};

function encrypt(message) {
  let chars = message.split('');
  return chars.map(c => {
    let charValue = BigInt(c.charCodeAt(0));
    return (charValue ** publicKey.e) % publicKey.n;
  });
}

function decrypt(message) {
  return message.map(c => {
    let charCode = (c ** privateKey.d) % privateKey.n;
    return String.fromCharCode(Number(charCode));
  }).join('');
}

let message = "i love cookies";
let crypt = encrypt(message);
console.log("Encrypted: ", crypt.map(e => e.toString()));
console.log("Decrypted: ", decrypt(crypt));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've changed the code, but still the same problem persists. There seems to be a problem with the letter-to-number process.

Comment: Update: the data is displayed, so in that sense it works, but the array given is always the same, regardless of the 'plaintext'. The text doesn't seem to be received correctly

Comment: @OlafWillner `return anum[str] || ' '` might be a bit problematic, because `' '` is not a number, what text input did you try?

Comment: @Turtleflight I changed the code to your answer (without return anum[str] || ' '), so what you sent is what I have currently. Thanks

Comment: @OlafWillner You need to choose `p` and `q` sufficiently large. I added a full encryption / decrpytion example to my answer

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I would like to calculate d and not treat it as a constant for security purposes (I wouldn't want the private key to always be the same), so I have written a way to calculate the modular inverse, but I think there's a problem with it mixing with BigInt. Here is the code: `var modInverse = function(a, b) {
    a %= b;
    for (var x = 1; x < b; x++) {
        if ((a*x)%b == 1) {
            return x;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @OlafWillner `var x = 1;` should be `var x =1n;` (the n denotes the number should be a BigInt) and the `== 1` should be `== 1n` as well.